# How do I draw an ESB on a SoaML diagram?

Tags: uml, esb

I've recently had to draw some architectural diagrams that feature the use of an [Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus).  The ESB is critical, so everyone wants it to show up on the diagram.  But since it's the center of what everything is connected to, it really of gets in the way.

I settled on trying to use [SoaML](http://www.omg.org/spec/SoaML/).  I color-coded the request points blue and service points green, to help then stand out.  The text names on the ports give you a sense of what talks to what, and it's incredibly obvious that everything goes through the ESB.

Can anyone comment on my approach?  Any suggestions on something better?

[image: SoaML diagram]

Comment: AFAIK I don't think there is any standard notation for ESB, but just my thought as the service providers are external to the ESB, shouldn't the ESB be abstract? Like it generally will have only infrastructural services which may not be useful for business directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's good. I'm using [Mule ESB](https://developer.mulesoft.com/) and the only thing I added was making the request and service points into inbound and outbound routers and the ESB as the service.